# Find high-volume log messages in sumologic

Tags: sumologic

I am trying to reduce logging costs using sumologic for a microservice I run.

My specific goal is to determine which log statements are costing the most money (or to put it in more easily query-able terms, which log statements are being called the most frequently by my service so I can analyze whether they're really adding value by being ingested into sumo).

I've been digging around the [Log Operators Cheat Sheet](https://help.sumologic.com/05Search/Search-Cheat-Sheets/Log-Operators-Cheat-Sheet) trying to figure it out and the closest thing I can find seems to be the count_frequent function, but I can't seem to figure out how to use it in a query.

Google has not been of much use in this case (or at least, I haven't really come up with a good search string that Google can latch onto and get me what I'm looking for).

Any help would be appreciated.